# pandas convert to wide table

Tags: python, pandas

I want convert my df to a single row wide table.
The input data is below:

```
data = {"headings": [{'heading':  'item1',
        'random_assignment_percent': 'item2',
        },
        {'heading':  'item3',
        'random_assignment_percent': 'item4',
                }]}
```

Table that we have:

```
___________________________________________
|   |heading    |random_assignment_percent|
|-----------------------------------------|
|0  |item1      |item2                    |
|1  |item3      |item4                    |
-------------------------------------------
```

And that I would like to have:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
|       |heading_0  |heading_1  |random_assignment_percent_0    |random_assignment_percent_1|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1  |item1      |item3      |item2                          |item4                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could someone help me to get my df exactly as on last table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be `unstack` + `transpose`:

```
out = df.unstack().to_frame().T
out.columns = out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format) 
print(out)
```

---

```
  heading_0 heading_1 random_assignment_percent_0 random_assignment_percent_1
0     item1     item3                       item2                       item4
```